# How to handle TCL_ERROR return from Tcl_EvalFile() in C?

Tags: c, tcl

I have a C program which invokes the TCL interpreter thru Tcl_EvalFile().  I am checking the status return by Tcl_EvalFile and know when it produces something different from TCL_OK.  However I am not getting any traceback reporting in my program like I would if I used `tclsh`.

I know about embedding C functions into TCL but that won't work in my case.  I am actually calling TCL from a C function that a Lua program is calling.  The example code shown is a simplified version.

Here is the call to Tcl_EvalFile():

```
  if ((status = Tcl_EvalFile(interp, script)) != TCL_OK)
    {
      /* I would like to handle the error here before Tcl_Exit()*/
      Tcl_Exit(status);
      return TCL_ERROR;
    }
```

Is there a TCL function that I can call which will produce the traceback message similar to what `tclsh` produces?

Comment: Did you check the Tcl documentation on [`Tcl_GetReturnOptions`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclLib/AddErrInfo.htm) plus working example?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  That is what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: You might want to consider posting a self-answer plus snippet to your own question, for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

The single most important thing you can do to handle an error is to print the error message out! The second most important thing is to print the stack trace. Tcl puts the error message in the interpreter result, and the stack trace in a special global variable, `errorInfo`.

```
if ((status = Tcl_EvalFile(interp, script)) != TCL_OK) {
    // Get the error message out of the way *right now*
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR when reading file %s: %s\n", script,
            Tcl_GetStringResult(interp));
    // Most convenient access for this is to run a tiny Tcl script.
    Tcl_Eval(interp, "puts {STACK TRACE:}; puts $errorInfo; flush stdout;");
    Tcl_Exit(status);
    return TCL_ERROR; // This should be unreachable; Tcl_Exit doesn't return...
}
```

Comment: You can also get the error trace out of the return options dictionary… but that's more work. `tclsh` reads the global variable.